# Crear variable fecha a partir de un string

Tags: javascript

Desde una api obtengo datos varios, entre estos datos viene un string de una fecha, este string viene en formato 'es-CL' el cual al intentar crear una variable con este string me aparece error

ej:

```
const stringDate = '23-10-2023 1:33:10';
new Date(stringDate) // Invalid Date
Date.parse(stringDate) // NaN
```

entonces **mi problema es como crear la variable de tipo `Date` con este string**, puedo saber en qué "locale" está formateado el string ya que es el mismo del navegador, es decir, `window.navigator.language` pero el formato no lo sé (que en este caso es 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'), necesito poder crear la variable con cualquier texto que venga porque esto puede ser ejecutado desde varios paises y va a depender de la configuración local del idioma del navegador

EDIT:

lo que estoy haciendo es una especie de "add-in" de una aplicación web que ya existe y el formato de la fecha que me entrega es siempre el del idioma del navegador, esto lo comprobé al cambiar el idioma del navegador a ingles estados unidos y la fecha que me entregó cambió el formato a "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" por eso lo que necesito concretamente es poder crear una fecha con un formato y poder saber el formato de la fecha de acuerdo al "language" o "locale" del navegador

Ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El problema es encontrar:

- El separador de la fecha (ejemplo: `-` o `/`)
- El orden de la fecha (ejemplo `MM-DD-YYYY` o `DD-MM-YYYY`)
- El `locale` del cliente
- El `offset` UTC del cliente

Esto datos se encuentran utilizando 2 funciones:

- `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale` : Te retorna el `locale` como por ejemplo `es-CL`
- `Intl.DateTimeFormat().formatToParts()`: Te retorna las partes de una fecha, el separador y el orden del array es el orden en que está compuesta la fecha (de izquierda a derecha), por ejemplo si en el array está primero el `day`, luego `month` y `year` es que es `DD-MM-YYYY`. Y por último está función tambien entrega el `offset`

Con esto el problema se reduce a ir buscando cada parte del string y limpiarlo si es necesario para formar un string valido como por ejemplo: `2023-11-02T07:30:21-03:00`

```js
const GetDate = (fecha, locale) => {
  locale = locale ?? Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale;
  fecha = fecha.replace(",",""); //limpiamos si trae coma
  
  const tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  const partesLocale =  Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
    timeZoneName: "longOffset"
  }).formatToParts();
  
  const separador = partesLocale.find(a=> a.type == "literal").value;
  
  const partesFecha = fecha.split(new RegExp(`${separador}| |:`,"gm"));
  
  const soloFecha =  partesLocale.filter(a=>a.type != "literal");
  
  const ano = partesFecha[soloFecha.findIndex(a=> a.type == "year")].padStart(4, '20'); //padStart para casos donde el año es YY así lo convertimos en YYYY
  const dia = partesFecha[soloFecha.findIndex(a=> a.type == "day")];
  const mes = partesFecha[soloFecha.findIndex(a=> a.type == "month")];
  
  const hora = partesFecha[3].padStart(2, '0'); //para cuando el número es una cifra, le agregamos el cero delante
  const min  = partesFecha[4].padStart(2, '0');
  const seg  = partesFecha[5].padStart(2, '0');
  
  const offset=  partesLocale.find(a=> a.type == "timeZoneName").value.replace("GMT","");
  
  return new Date(`${ano}-${mes}-${dia}T${hora}:${min}:${seg}${offset}`);
  
};

//DEMO
const fecha = new Date();
const fechaString = fecha.toLocaleString();
console.log(GetDate(fechaString));


//OTROS =================

//es-CL
console.log(GetDate('23-10-2023 1:33:10',"es-CL"));

//en-US
console.log(GetDate('12/19/2012 1:33:10',"en-US"));


//en-GB
console.log(GetDate('20/12/2012 1:33:10',"en-GB"));

//ko-KR
console.log(GetDate('2012. 12. 20. 1:33:10',"ko-KR"));

//ja-JP-u-ca-japanese
console.log(GetDate('24/12/20 1:33:10',"ja-JP"));
```

Comment: lo que estoy haciendo es una especie de "add-in" de una aplicación web que ya existe y el formato de la fecha que me entrega es siempre el del idioma del navegador, esto lo comprobé al cambiar el idioma del navegador a ingles estados unidos y la fecha que me entregó cambió el formato a "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" por eso lo que necesito concretamente es poder crear una fecha con un formato y poder saber el formato de la fecha de acuerdo al "language" o "locale" del navegador

Answer (score 0):

A ver si así, ya me dirás si esta vez he acertado en lo que necesitas y te funciona bien:

```
var fechaString = "11-05-2023 14:30:00"; // La fecha en esta variable string

var components = fechaString.split(/[\s:-]/); // Esta línea separa el string por guiones y dos puntos, en este caso día, mes, año, hora, minuto, segundo

var fechaHoraNueva = new Date(components[2], components[1] - 1, components[0], components[3], components[4], components[5]); // Ahora se crea un nuevo objeto Date así, con los componentes de la línea de antes

console.log(fechaHoraNueva); // Y esta línea para comprobar que funciona
```

---

Este era el código que te he dado antes y que no vale, no sé si tengo que borrarlo, te lo dejo por si te sirve para otras cosas:

Si te he entendido bien, quieres obtener la fecha y hora local, pasarla a string, cambiar el formato de fecha y volver a pasarla a Date, todo con JavaScript. Si lo que quieres hacer es lo que creo, prueba esto.

1. Primero, obtén la fecha y hora del servidor local del usuario
2. Segundo, crea un objeto para decirle a JavaScript el formato de la fecha y hora que quieres
3. Después, pásalo a string
4. Para terminar, vuelve a pasar el string a date

Ahora, a verlo en código:

```
var fechaHoraActual = new Date(); // Obtener la fecha y hora local del usuario

var options = { // Crear un objeto para dar formato a la fecha como dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss, llámalo options o como quieras llamarlo
   day: '2-digit',
   month: '2-digit',
   year: 'numeric',
   hour: '2-digit',
   minute: '2-digit',
   second: '2-digit'
};

var fechaHoraFormateada = fechaHoraActual.toLocaleString(undefined, options); // Pasar la hora local a string: undefined usa la configuración regional predeterminada del navegador del usuario, options es el objeto que has creado y controla el formato en que muestra la fecha y hora

var fechaHoraNueva = new Date(fechaHoraFormateada); // Crear una fecha a partir de la cadena formateada

console.log(fechaHoraNueva); // Esto te mostrará en consola la fecha y hora en el formato deseado, para comprobar si ya es lo que necesitas, cuando ya esté bien, esta línea de código no la necesitarás
```

Comment: No es ese el problema. La entrada es un `string` el cual hay que pasarlo a `Date`. Ese string está en un formato que varía según la configuración `locale` del cliente.

Comment: de todos modos el código está bueno para tener en cuenta en otras soluciones pero no es exactamente lo que necesito

Answer (score -3):

Aquí tienes un codigo bien explicado hecho por mi :D, aparte no necesitas ninguna api para obtener la hora, es muy sencillo como esto:

```javascript
// Obtener la fecha y hora actuales
var fecha = new Date();

// Obtener la zona horaria del dispositivo
var zonaHoraria = fecha.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

// Ajustar la hora según la zona horaria
fecha.setHours(fecha.getHours() + zonaHoraria);

// Convertir la hora en formato HH:MM:SS
var hora = ("0" + fecha.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + fecha.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + fecha.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

// Mostrar la hora actual y zona horaria
console.log("La hora actual es: " + hora + ", en la zona horaria GMT" + (zonaHoraria >= 0 ? "+" : "-") + Math.abs(zonaHoraria));
```

Comment: está muy bien pero esa respuesta no es para mi problema, tengo un string y quiero crear una variable `Date` pero me arroja error

Comment: Entonces no te puedo ayudar, lo siento, yo programo sencillo, puedes coger mi ejemplo o esperar a otra respuesta :)